# How to add icon for stacked navigation in react native?

Tags: react-native

does anyone know how to add an icon to stacked navigation? The home icon was appearing until I added stacked navigation to add a button onto the homepage.

Here is the complete navigation code for reference:

```
const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  introFlow: createStackNavigator({
    Intro: IntroScreen,
  }),
  mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: createStackNavigator({
      HomePage: {
        screen: HomeScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel:'Home',
          tabBarIcon:({focused})=>(  
            <Icon name="home" color={focused ? 'lightseagreen' : 'slategray'} size={25}/>   
        ) 
        }},
        Train: {
          screen: TrainScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:'Train',
            tabBarIcon:({focused})=>(  
              <Icon name="home" color={focused ? 'lightseagreen' : 'slategray'} size={25}/>   
          ) 
          }},
    }),
    Graph: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel:'History',
        tabBarIcon:({focused})=>(  
          <Icon name="bar-chart" color={focused ? 'lightseagreen' : 'slategray'} size={25}/>   
      ) 
      }},
      Profile: {
        screen: GraphScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
          tabBarLabel:'Profile',
          tabBarIcon:({focused})=>(  
            <Icon name="person" color={focused ? 'lightseagreen' : 'slategray'} size={25}/>   
        ) 
        }},
        Tutorial: {
          screen: ProfileScreen,
          navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:'Tutorial',
            tabBarIcon:({focused})=>(  
              <Icon name="help-circle" color={focused ? 'lightseagreen' : 'slategray'} size={25}/>  
          ) 
          }},
    }),
    
});
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you to use older version of react navigation? react navigation v6 is almost out. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/tab-based-navigation/#a-stack-navigator-for-each-tab follow this, it shows you how exactly create stack navs for each tabs, then you can modify the tabBarIcon for each tabs, not for each stacks as you are doing. You can't set tabBarIcon in a Stack Screen.

Comment: Thanks, Bora! I was following a tutorial I found and didn't realize it was outdated. I will update to the newer version.

Comment: Awesome! No worries!